# What's wrong with this evaluation of $\lim _{x\to 2^-} \frac{|2x-x^2|}{x-2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

[image: lim of a fraction with absolute value]

Suppose we want to evaluate
$$\lim _{x\to 2^-} \frac{|2x-x^2|}{x-2}$$

Note that multiple answer choices may be correct.

I marked A and C as correct.
The websystem marked this incorrect.
I drew a graph of $-x^2 +2x$, parabola facing down, above the x-axis 0 < x < 2
So $|2x-x^2|  = -x^2 + 2x$ in the relevant interval.

Comment: Note: your image link at the end must be a whole clear line apart from the main text; this is why your image wasn’t displaying

Comment: $A$ is clearly incorrect due to the reasoning (counter-example $x=-1$)

Comment: but in context of a limit, x->2- we don't need to care about x<0

Comment: Sorry about the purple, which is irrelevant.  I'm actually an online tutor and made those while explaining something to the student.

Also, thanks @FShrike and to PM 2Ring.

Comment: What's the mathjax for properly writing a limit?

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12850/161490 (including the comments). Note that `\limits` is rarely necessary, and that limits display differently depending whether they're inline or not.

Answer (score 6):

It is not true that $|2x-x^{2}|=2x-x^{2}$ for all $x <2$: Take $x <0$ to see why.  So A) is not correct. The correct one is  C).

Comment: but in context of a limit,  x->2- we don't need to care about x<0.

Comment: @nickalh the justification for A is still wrong, with an inaccurate statement

Comment: That is  trre as far as finding the limit is concerned but you still cannot say that $|2x-x^{2}|=2x-x^{2}$ for all $x <2$. That is logically incorrect.

Comment: @nickalh (A) doesn't only contain your circled parts.  The justification included the incorrect statement "$\lvert 2x-x^2\rvert=2x-x^2$ for (all) $x<2$" instead of what you want to read "... for (all) $x<2$ that is sufficiently close to 2".

Comment: See "Sorry about the purple, which is irrelevant. I'm actually an online tutor and made those while explaining something to the student", LOL.

Comment: Actually, the original question does *not* have "all".  I guess for some it's common or Ok to assume in the vicinity of 2 but others don't accept that.

Comment: In statement  a) there is no difference between 'for $x<2$' and  'for all $x<2$'. @nickalh

Comment: @nickalh The question and suggested answers do not have to include the word “all”, as there is no other reasonable way to interpret $x < 2$. If we are going to start saying “in the context of a limit”, then we had might as well get rid of the interval entirely and just say that $2x - x^2 > 0$. Also, the complex notation used in answers (C) and (D) should have made it clear that interval notation is a key part of this question.

Answer (score 3):

There's no ambiguity here. The statement about the limit is correct, but the second statement is wrong simply because $|2x-x^2|=2x-x^2$ holds for $0<x<2$ and not $x<2$. There is no difference between $\textrm{for all }x<2$ and $\textrm{for }x<2$. The reason given is not given as a complement to the limit equation, but is given as an eternal statement which you need to check whether it's correct.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Your way to start by drawing the graph of the parabola is a good start

[image]

from this we see that as $x \to 2^-$, that is eventually for $0<x<2$ we have that $2x-x^2>0$ so itsn't true that $|2x-x^2|  = -x^2 + 2x$ but $|2x-x^2|  = 2x-x^2$ and therefore we can exclude choices $B$ and $D$.

We also need to exclude choice $A$ for the reasons well explained in the other answers.